# Disable creating wav file when using QAudioRecorder

Tags: c++, qt, qaudiorecorder

I am developing app witch may sample audio from microphone. I have used QAudioRecorder and QAudioProbe to sample. Everything works fine. But I have just realized the QAudioRecorder saves recorded audio to my documents. Maybe I should use QAudioInput instead. I will do it all again if I must. But, is there any way to disable creation of that audio file? I have my samples. I don't need them on my harddrive. Thank you for help.

Comment: You could change the output location to a temp file or `/dev/null`, but it seems kind of weird to use a class that has "Recorder" in the name if you don't want to record something.

Comment: It is weird I know. But this solution gives me control about how many samples will pass to fft (i need fixed size of array). QAudioInput has only time signal in ms.

Comment: It is not wired IMO, because it records, just not directly to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, a storage location is inherent to `QAudioRecorder`, and you must use a lower-level way to "capture audio" without storing it to disk.

Here is a minimal example using `QAudioInput`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimedia-audioinput-example.html

Comment: Thank you for advice. I didn't find any way to emit signal when the buffer is full. When buffer is filled the program copy it to merge array witch is used for 50 % overlaps. Here is my fully functional program... only problem is that created [file](https://github.com/fpartl/PocketEar/blob/master/recorder.cpp) on GitHub. I don't know how I can do this using QAudioInput.